# How to install dBase extension (php 5.4.7 on Windows)?

Tags: php, installation, dbase

I'm trying to install dBase extension for php, but with no success so far. Searching the site, I found this link, http://downloads.php.net/pierre/, and downloaded php_dbase.dll from there. Then I added "extension=php_dbase.dll" line in php.ini (and restarted apache), but it's not working. Other suggestions/solutions I found were related to compiling php with --enable-dbase option, or installing a PECL extesion. As I'm unfamiliar with this aproaches, I searched for some instructions, but I was unable to follow them. PECL extensions have no .dlls I could copy to \php\ext\ folder.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://hrazdil.info/blog/414-php-dbase-extension-for-php-5-4-windows-nts-ts-vc9